# Can I request a check for my work?

Tags: support, allowed-questions, asking-questions

I want to be sure some of my answers for some exercises are correct. Simply, I want to learn that can I post them and request a check at Mathematics SE?

Comment: Yes, people do this all the time. However, don't use the word "demand". It is as close to a guaranteed way of getting no replies as is possible...

Comment: Sorry English is not my first language, and thanks.

Comment: I figured that - just thought I'd point it out though!

Comment: At first I thought the OP was asking for monetary compensation.  And then I thought the OP wanted his/her answers to be selected (given a check mark).

Comment: (solution-verification) tag exists